# Inelegant structural repetition in parser combinators

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

While parsing some complex text, where I need to split out regular expression definitions for reuse and readability reasons, I seem to be often ending up with Scala code of this general structure (`pn` - a regex pattern, `vn` a variable):

```
val cp1 = p1 ~ p2 ~ p3 ~ p4 ~ p5 ~ p6 ^^
          case { dummy1 ~ v2 ~ dummy3 ~ v4 ~ dummy5 ~ v6 => ACaseClass(v2, v4, v6) }
```

The obvious issue is the readability and maintainability of the code as new patterns need to be inserted because of the separation of the useful matches (`vn`) from the placeholder ones (`dummyn`).

So, is there a neater way to express the intent? Could I use `_` instead for every `dummyn`?

In the SNOBOL language, one could write `(pat . var)` or `(pat $ var)` which would assign the result of the match to the variable; similarly, in the latest regex syntax we have named capture groups `(?P<name>pat)`. The intent is clearly to keep the match capture variable close to the pattern.

So, what I would like to write is something along the general lines of:

```
val cp1 = p1 ~ ( p2 $$ v2 )  ~ p3 ~ ( p4 $$ v4 ) ~ p5 ~ ( p6 $$ v6 ) $=>
          ACaseClass(v2, v4, v6)
```

Obviously I am assuming some sort of new operators `$$` and `$=>` which enable this simpler syntax.

Conceivably macros could help, but they are rather beyond my abilities at present. Any input welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Why didn't you try using `_`? It turns out that it works. Also you can use `~>` and `<~` to discard parts of your pattern, although you'll need to use parenthesis if you want to discard inner parts.

```
object SimpleScala extends JavaTokenParsers {

  def test = "(" ~> wholeNumber ~ ("," ~> wholeNumber <~ ",") ~ wholeNumber <~ ")" ^^ 
    { case i1 ~ i2 ~ i3 => (i1,i2,i3) }

  def test2 = "(" ~ wholeNumber ~ "," ~ wholeNumber ~ ")" ^^ 
    { case _ ~ i1 ~ _ ~i2 ~ _ => (i1,i2) }

  def main(args: Array[String]){
    println(parseAll(test,"(42,34,5)"))
    println(parseAll(test2,"(42,345)"))
  }
}
```